# Can anybody explain the error in the program i made, can anybody why i didn't workout?

Tags: c, debugging

how is your day :),
Take a look at the below program, the program written below is to calculate the sum of first n natural numbers, the problem is that i get the sum of n-1 natural numbers, can anybody explain why ?

and can anybody also explain why a-- instead of --a.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int a,sum;
    printf("Enter a number.");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    sum=sumnat(a);
    printf("Sum of the first %d natural numbers is %d.",a,sum);
}
sumnat(a)
{
    int b;
    if(a==0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        b=a+sumnat(--a);
        return(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: pass in a `-1` and you will overflow the stack because it will recurse forever

Comment: @self, but this is plainly normal in this website!

Comment: have you read the code? `a == 0` is the exit point for the recursion

Comment: yes it is, but why a-- wouldn't work and only --a

Comment: Neither `main` nor `sumnat` have a type defined. Enable compiler warnings, and use a prototype too.

Comment: Where are you initializing `b`?

Comment: i have initialized b at the start of sumnat(a) @JohnColeman

Comment: No -- you didn't. You *declared* `b`

Comment: @WeatherVane and and how can i do that ?

Comment: @JohnColeman  if i intialize b=0 will that work

Comment: Not really -- you still have undefined behavior. Don't use `a` and `--a` in the same expression since you can't control the order of evaluation.

Comment: @JohnColeman that's actually a good point, but can you just explain a little bit on how the order of evaluation is taking place

Comment: If you are still using things like `main()` with no return type and are struggling with the distinction between defining a variable and initializing it -- your time would be better spent learning the fundamentals of the language than worrying about recursion and undefined behavior.

Comment: thank you john, but christopher schneider answered my question in the second answer to this post, i appreciate your help sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were several errors, the greatest of which was undefined behaviour in the expression which uses `a` and also a modified value of `a`. You should also define your function properly, not rely on default values provided by the compiler.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sumnat(int a);                  // function prototype

int main(void)                      // correct signature
{
    int a, sum;
    printf("Enter a number. ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    sum = sumnat(a);
    printf("Sum of the first %d natural numbers is %d.", a, sum);
    return 0;
}

int sumnat(int a)                   // function has a return type and argument type
{
    if(a == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return a + sumnat(a - 1);       // there was no need to decrement `a`
}
```

Program session

```
Enter a number. 5
Sum of the first 5 natural numbers is 15.
```

Comment: @WeatheVane thanks so much, i've finally found the flaw,
the fact is that until the final (or the last) recursion takes place the value of a in the expression b=a+sumnat(--a); is not returned and when it does, it is 0 , because of the condition 

if(a==0)
return 0;

and also because the execution of the parameters takes place from right to left.

Comment: I can't stress enough, that `b=a+sumnat(--a)` is *undefined behaviour*. If it worked on one computer, it's called "lucky".

Comment: @WeatherVane ..or "unfortunate" depending on your level of pedanticism.

Answer (score 0):

Your program works for me, using gcc on Mac OSX.  However, it will not work everywhere, because of this line:

```
b=a+sumnat(--a);
```

`--a` decrements `a`, but if it does so before the addition, then your result will be wrong.  I'm not sure C is required to evaluate expressions strictly left-to-right (I don't think it is).  At any rate, since you don't use `a` after that line, you could fix things this way:

```
b=a+sumnat(a-1);
```

As @self says, you should fix the program to handle negative values, and it would be a good idea to consider what is the largest natural number whose sum you can compute this way (and why that is).

Comment: why does the program recurse infinitely if i use a - - ?

Comment: [Replying to a deleted comment, sorry]
True.  I just didn't want to claim that it was definitely wrong, because I'm not up-to-date on C standards.  It's certainly a Really Bad Idea to do it that way, but for all I know, a recent standard update makes it legal.
Regarding the initialization of `b`, though, I don't think that's wrong.  It's certainly not best practices, but he's not using an uninitialized value (he's just not initializing it at the preferred time).
The whole subroutine could be replaced with `return (a <= 0) ? 0 : a + sumnat( a - 1 );`

Comment: `a--` is a _post_ decrement. The value of a isn't actually decremented until you return from `sumnat()`.

Comment: in other words, if `a = 1`, `sumnat(a--)` is essentially identical to `sumnat(a); a--;` You will then never successfully decrement `a` and will end up in an infinite loop.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider superb thank you so much that's all i needed.
the fact is that until the final (or the last) recursion takes place the value of a in the expression  

b=a+sumnat(--a);

is not returned and when it does, it is 0, wow, i'm thrilled, superb.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider "The value of a isn't actually decremented until you return from sumnat()" - that is wrong. `a--` decrements `a` after obtaining the initial value in a temp, then uses that temp as the value of the resulting expression. For the OP's case, it doesn't matter, because its use in the same statement as `a` invokes UB regardless, but it is an important distinction never-the-less. [See **here**](http://ideone.com/6QHquX). That behavior is one of the main reasons post-operators are so hideously expensive in languages like C++ when overloaded for complex types.

Comment: @WhozCraig Interesting. I wasn't aware of that. Quite an odd scenario, which is why I had always assumed the postfix happened after the return. Seems like there might be a story behind discovering that.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider You have that story thrust upon you rather brutally the first time you implement a custom iterator type supporting post-increment/decrement in C++, believe me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between them. One first subracts from a and than goes in the function while the other frist goes in... so it never gets subracted and you go to inifinit stack.

Answer (score 0):

"and can anybody also explain why a-- instead of --a"

When you use the prefix operator *--a* the decrease is done before anything else, while the postfix operator *a--* happens after the rest of the expression is resolved, so, lets say, while debugging your code, in a particular moment, a = 5
since the line

```
b=a+sumnat(--a);
```

is using the prefix version of the operator, the decrement would happen immediately, making a=4 and then the function sumnat would be called with argument 4

```
b=a+sumnat(a--);
```

in this case the postfix operator is being used, so first the function sumnat would be called with the argument 5, since that is the value of a in that moment, then, only when the function returns a value (which would never happen in your example, since it would be called multiple times with the same value, never reaching 0) the decrement would happen

Comment: Why do *either* posfix or prefix. Just use `b = a + sumnat(a-1)`